# How to disable all Log of RabbitMQ or set config to rotation log with date ? [Windows]

Tags: windows, logging, rabbitmq

I have problem with rabbitmq logs in server because the file is very large when my shovels could not connect to destination server .

I try to set rabbitmq.config with this

```
[
   {rabbit, [{log_levels,[{connection, error}]}]}
].
```

and this

```
[{rabbit, [
        {log, [
            {file, [{enabled, false}]}
        ]}
]}].
```

but after setting config with this, log files are still creating in this name: RABBIT~1.LOG  and RABBIT~2.LOG

Can anyone help me set config to disable all log files   or  set config to rotate log files with date ?

My RabbitMQ version is 3.6.14 and Erlang version is 18.1

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade to a more recent version of RabbitMQ and Erlang. The `18.X` Erlang series is known to have issues.

RabbitMQ 3.7.X uses the `lager` library which supports being disabled completely if you wish to do so. But that is a very bad idea because you won't have any visibility into your system if an error arises.

I recommend enabling log rotation in `lager` instead. See the "Logging to a File" section in this document:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but i have limitation on version of rabbitmq and erlang because the environment on my client don't support later versions.